# How to debug "undefined" 404 error in console on front page

Tags: debugging

I'm getting a strange 404 error on the front page only, which seems to be causing some other issues for me. I'm hopeful if I solve this it will take care of those, too.

On the front page only, when I load the console, I see the following error:

[image: Undefined 404 in console]

I am not sure what would be causing this as the page appears to load correctly and it isn't giving much of a clue as to what it is trying to load.

How do I debug from this point?

Comment: It's a javascript problem, e.g. `$.get('/foo/' + someVar);`, where `someVar` is `undefined` will make a request to /foo/undefined

Comment: To debug, I'd look at the "Network" tab and see when this "undefined" path is being requested. The neighbouring requests might help you distinguish when it's being called or even where it's being called from (Some type of loop most likely).

I always assumed that `(index):1` suggests that it's originating from a <script> tag (without a "src" attribute) on that page. Although that might be a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips Clive and Beebee!

By trial and error I disabled or removed various components until I found one that made the error go away. In this case it seems to be a problem with Flexslider and Views that was used in a Views block -- I haven't solved it yet but have isolated it at least!

**UPDATE:** It seems to be a bug related to the navigation in the Flexslider module (Views integration). If I set the Flexslider style not to include navigation, it is fine.